# POSIX Message Queue go through kernel space?

Tags: linux, posix, message-queue

I am looking to use POSIX message queues on a single process multi threaded application.  mqueues will be used to share data between the threads.

I am a little confused on how they work in the Linux kernel.  Do all the messages go through kernel space and then back to user space on the receive?  a.k.a. from a userspace thread I do a mq_send and the message ends up in kernel space, and then on receive it is another system call to get the message from kernel space.  If so isn't this highly inefficient for high-use message queues?

Comment: One warning, aimed more at future readers than you: be aware that SysV IPC objects such as message queues are persistent. If your program creates one but does not delete it, *it will persist after the program exits*. Think of queues as being more like files than sockets (only harder to manage, because they have IDs rather than paths). Consider creating them in the installation process rather than during execution.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: POSIX message queues aren't the same as SysV ones; they are also persistent and like files, but under Linux, you can mount the filesystem, see them and remove them with "rm". POSIX message queues have names not numbers.

Comment: @MarkR: That is a great point which i had completely missed - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they will always go through the kernel (and were generally used for inter-process communication). If you just want inter-thread communication, you can probably do that via. a simple worker queue (using plain old mutexes).

If you want something with more features, you are almost certainly better off looking at something like AMQP.

Traditionally Unix/Linux has used sockets+read/write instead, but it depends on what you want (and how you want to use it).

Comment: Pipes may be another alternative. I don't know mqueues are implemented, but the tee/splice discussion suggests that pipes work as efficiently as can be under Linux. Apparently, pipes mostly work by remapping pages, never doing a copy that is not absolutely necessary. Torvalds mentioned at some point that they even wanted to rewrite the sendfile call to run over the pipe mechanism because it's allegedly much faster.

Comment: I was going to use a Unix socket but it is byte based and really wanted something that was message/packet oriented as that is what they will be used for.
I am thinking a simple mutex locked C++ std::queue may work for me.

Comment: @RishiD: you can create unix-domain datagram sockets. Just pass the same flags you'd use to create an internet domain datagram (ie UDP) socket but with the AF_UNIX type. Note that the datagrams will still go via the kernel, though. For your purposes, a userland structure using a futex is probably the best bet, as James suggests.

Answer (score 6):

Well I have to object to the notion that MQs are "highly" inefficient.

It is true that there is some overhead involved in copying data to/from the kernel and for truly high performance applications this might be a real consideration and reason to use shared or heap memory instead.

But short of well written shared memory code MQs are the fastest IPC around and come with substantial built-in facilities.  The synchonization headaches are removed and (under linux at least) the message queue descriptor (mqd_t) can be used as a file descriptor in a select() statement.  This allows for considerable flexiblity for doing something other than waiting on a mutex or constantly polling one.  Additionally MQs are kernel persistent and that is a nice little feature if it is important that the queue data survive an application crash.

Comment: Great point about mqd_t can be used in select() this is useful for my application.  Thanks for the tip.